# Outlook 2013 - Notification Bar "not most recent mail" missing

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, notifications

I'm using Outlook 2013 (german) in an enterprise environment.

When you try to answer to an email, which was answered in the meantime, Outlook shows a notification bar. It's telling you, that you're not answering on the most recent mail in this thread.
See here for a screenshot of this notification bar:

[image]

The text says "You're not answering to the most recent message of this conversation. Please click here to open it".

Unfortunately I don't get this message anymore. I've connected some personal workflows to this message, so I want to get this notification back.

So how to enable the message bar again?
Thanks for your help in advance.

Phil

Comment: Its likely that you need to enable/disable caching mode.

Comment: Yeah, never thought about that. I enabled the cached mode and got the notification bar again. Disabled the cached mode and the notification is gone. Can I have this bar with the cache mode disabled?

Comment: No. Without the cachingmode, you work "online". It takes too much time to search for other messages so outlook disables it. I'll add a solution so we can solve this question so others can find their problem too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are working online.

If you enable caching mode, outlook will create an .OST file with all emails in it.

Outlook can then index your email, and because of the index, it knows when an email is not the latest email and thus can give you this notification.